# Separate "Curl POST's" with data from json file - Windows CMD Shell

Tags: json, api, curl, cmd, jq

I'm working on an API connection, I am receiving JSON datasets which contain multiple objects and I'm trying to pass that through to the next system.

The JSON dataset has the following information (OUTPUT.JSON):

```json
[
  {
    "initials": "V.",
    "firstName": "Victor",
    "lastNamePrefix": " ",
    "lastName": "Rutherford",
    "employerReferenceId": "0258741",
    "jobDescription": "Rental"
  },
  {
   "initials": "P.",
    "firstName": "Pippa",
    "lastNamePrefix": " ",
    "lastName": "Lewis",
    "employerReferenceId": "98765431",
    "jobDescription": "Rental"
  },
  {
    "initials": "S.",
    "firstName": "Stephanie",
    "lastNamePrefix": " ",
    "lastName": "Reid",
    "employerReferenceId": "123456789",
    "jobDescription": "Rental"
  }
]
```

The API post I'm trying to do has to be a separate Post for each object (person) in the JSON datafile.
This because the post has to have the referencenumber of the EMPLOYERREFEREBCEID in the URL for each post, but the post also needs to only have the section of data that belongs to that EMPLOYERREFEREBCEID in the JSON file.

```
curl -X POST "https://website.eu/test-Company/api2/external-employees/[EMPLOYERREFEREBCEID]" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token {TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@output.json"
```

I did found an old post that works with JQ and Bash, but since I am running Windows Server 2016 this is going to be challenging

```
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#id[@]} ; i++ ))
do 
     POST REST API 
done
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271307/post-json-data-with-curl-from-a-while-loop-bash-shell

Comment: In a nutshell, the question is "how to translate this bash/shell code to Windows". Can you install WSL or Git Bash/Cygwin? I found that the easiest solution, most of the time. Or use Python, it can handle JSON just fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to use Git, i was able to install it.
But now i run into the next situation, and its ok eventualy it wil work.

i am running the following code.

for i in `cat JSON\SENDER\output.json  | jq .glossary[].personnelNumber`; do 
   curl -X POST URL/test-suite/api2/external-employees/$i" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token {.......}/" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
done

but i recieve the following error.

bash: Send.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: Send.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: you have a double quote after your URL, but not before it. Unrelated, but certainly something to start doing: put single quotes around your jq expression to avoid the shell interfering with it (`[…]` is a shell wildcard).

Comment: Thanks for your input, im very new to this type of coding but i am trying sooo hard to get this working!
`for i in $(cat "c:\Test\output.json" | jq -r .[].employerReferenceId); do`
is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), for which this is a relatively easy task.
No need for FOR-loops. One `xidel` call could be enough.

```
xidel -s "OUTPUT.JSON" -e ^"^
  for $x in $json() return^
  x:request({^
    'headers':(^
      'accept: application/json',^
      'Authorization: Token %TOKEN%',^
      'Content-Type: application/json'^
    ),^
    'post':serialize($x,{'method':'json'}),^
    'url':'https://website.eu/test-Company/api2/external-employees/'^|^|$x/employerReferenceId^
  })/json^
"
```

This is the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) prettified version (with the necessary escape-characters).
Or alternatively the minified version:

```
xidel -s "OUTPUT.JSON" -e "for $x in $json() return x:request({'headers':('accept: application/json','Authorization: Token %TOKEN%','Content-Type: application/json'),'post':serialize($x,{'method':'json'}),'url':'https://website.eu/test-Company/api2/external-employees/'||$x/employerReferenceId})"
```

For each JSON-object (person) [`x:request()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-request) sends a POST-request. As you can see, it accepts options as a JSON-object.

- The 3 headers you can simply add as a sequence. (*this is assuming the `%TOKEN%`-variable is set beforehand*)
- The POST-data needs to be serialized! For the first JSON-object for instance this will be POSTed:

```
{"initials":"V.","firstName":"Victor","lastNamePrefix":" ","lastName":"Rutherford","employerReferenceId":"0258741","jobDescription":"Rental"}
```

- The base-url with the value of the `employerReferenceId`-attribute added. The url for the first JSON-object for instance: `https://website.eu/test-Company/api2/external-employees/0258741`.
- `x:request()`'s output is also a JSON-object. If this url/api also returns JSON, then you can parse it by selecting the `json`-attribute: `x:request(...)/json`. If not, then `x:request(...)/raw`.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, looks like an awesome tool.
I am running a test now but i am getting an error `Error: err:XPTY0004: Invalid conversion from` and then it showes the json and the serialization, but the serialization looks no different from the actual json, it btw doesnt continue with the code, after the error it stops.

Comment: @Randy Please use [the recommended latest release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/), or use `serialize-json($x)` instead of `serialize($x,{'method':'json'})`.

Comment: Yes, thank you Reino, this works like a champ!

Comment: how can i get xidel to work when i want to send a post to every employerReferenceId but the actual data is fixed json?
im trying to send something like `xidel -s outputlatest.json -e "for $x in $json() return x:request({'headers':('accept: application/json','Authorization: Token %TOKEN%','Content-Type: application/json'),'post-raw':'[{"contractReference":"empty","building":100,"floor":99}]','url':'https://website.eu/test-Company/api2/external-employees/'||$x/employerReferenceId})"` but i get a Internet/HTTP Error: 400 in return, am i missing something?

Comment: @Randy Escape the double quotes: `'[{\"contractReference\":\"empty\",\"building\":100,\"floor\":99}]'`. Or again use `serialize()`: `serialize(array{{'contractReference':'empty','building':100,'floor':99}},{'method':'json'})`. Btw, please use `'post'`. `'post-raw'` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This took me soo long but.. i have the first part working.

Solved!

```
for i in $(cat "c:\Test\output.json" | jq -r .[].employerReferenceId); do
```

After this part is start the Curl Command, wich also works fine till the data part, and thats where im stuck now.

```
curl -X POST "https://website.eu/test-Company/api2/external-employees/$i" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token {TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "EXAMPLE: $initials:value $firstName:value $lastNamePrefix:value $lastName:value $employerReferenceId:value $jobDescription:value"
```

Problem: how to reffer to the corresponding value's that belong to person in $i in the curl command data section.